# Js DOM манипуляции

Tags: javascript

Я учу js. И столкнулась с практическим заданием.
У меня есть большой див. И 10 маленьких дивов. Нужно, чтобы кликнув на маленький див, его содержимое копировалось в большой див. Маленькие дивы содержат картинку и параграф.

Буду очень признательна!

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так:

```js
var small = document.querySelectorAll('.small'); // Получили все мелкие блоки
var demo  = document.getElementById('demo');

for( let i = 0; i < small.length; i++ ){ /* Перебираем их, и по очереди вешаем на кажого
  событие 'click'. Здесь это работает благодаря let. Был бы var - не сработало бы*/
  small[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    demo.innerHTML = this.innerHTML; // здесь this == small[i];
    // внутри нужного блока помещаем внутренности текущего кликнутого.
  });
}
```

```css
.small {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px; margin: 3px;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.small img {width: 80px;}

p { text-align: center; margin: 0;}

#demo { display: block; margin: 10px auto; width: 120px;}
#demo img {width: 120px;}
```

```html
<div class="small">
  <img src="https://gyazo.com/0d017714eb3a95acf9efc7caf9949112.png">
  <p>Чебурашка</p>
</div>
<div class="small">
  <img src="https://gyazo.com/df1042ec92bd24d3e01188c650e06905.png">
  <p>Eva Green</p>
</div>
<div class="small">
  <img src="https://gyazo.com/4aaff87a0a3729241f10489325a3b92b.png">
  <p>Котик</p>
</div>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

http://learn.javascript.ru/ - удобно всё разложено по пунктам. 

Можете начать с пунктов `2.15` (про циклы), и во второй части `1.7` (про innerHTML)

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! Вы добрый :)

Comment: @Marina у Вас есть возможность отметить один из ответов, как «верный», нажав на галочку слева от ответа.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Вариант решения через делегирование событий:
document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let target = event.target,
    content;

  if (target.classList.contains('big')) {
    return;
  } else if (target.parentNode.tagName == 'DIV') {
    content = target.parentNode.innerHTML;
  } else if (target.tagName == 'DIV') {
    content = target.innerHTML;
  }

  let big = document.querySelector('.big');
  big.innerHTML = content;

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='big'>
    <!-- Основной див -->
  </div>
    <!-- Вторичные дивы -->
  <div>
    <p>
      Test1
    </p>
    <p>
      Test2
    </p>>
  </div>
  <div>
   Test3
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Хотя вариант Оптимуса намного рациональнее, мой тоже имеет право на жизнь :)

Comment: Спасибо, Владислав, что не поленились :)